# List Comprehension Python nested

Tags: python, list

```
answer = [list(x) for x in sorted(["HELLO", "WORLD", "SLEEPING", "CITY"])][1]
```

Could someone explain why the value of `answer` is not `["C","I","T","Y"]`?

Comment: Indexing in Python starts with 0 - `[1]` selects the **second** item from the list.

Comment: Did it occur to you to run `sorted(["HELLO", "WORLD", "SLEEPING", "CITY"])` by itself so you could see what the list comprehension is actually iterating over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
answer = [list(x) for x in sorted(["HELLO", "WORLD", "SLEEPING", "CITY"])][0]
```

You need to refer to the 0th element.